# Last digits are changed to zeros when exporting to Excel

Tags: excel

Using Oracle excel instance to export data to a spreadsheet. The column contains 700k rows and each has an 18 digit number (example: 123018062333567222). Once the export is complete, the numbers on the spreadsheet are changed to 123018062333567000 with three trailing zeros replacing the digits. How can the three trailing zeros be changed back to digits? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @D.O., it looks like you've never selected a correct answer to any of your questions. If an answer resolves your issue, please remember to mark it as correct. This closes the question.

Comment: @Michael Doing so doesn't really close the question, but makes it known that a solution for the problem was found. I usually point to this [website help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel numeric precision is 15 digits. You need to cast and export it as a string and the text excel data type will be able to handle your 18 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a number precision limit of 15 digits:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

You'll need to convert the number to a string before exporting.

You may also need to enclose the number in quotation marks or add a leading apostrophe to prevent Excel automatically converting the string back to a number.